# Biology: Wright-Fisher model of genetic drift

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, mathematical-modeling, applications, biology

In evolutionary biology (in population genetics to be more accurate) exists the concept of genetic drift. It describes how an [allele (gene variant)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allele) (that has no advantage or disadvantage in terms of reproductive succes) vary through time. Below is a classical model to describe this process of genetic drift. This model is called the Wright-Fisher model of genetic drift:

$$\frac{(2N)!}{k!(2N-k)!}p^kq^{2N-k} \Leftrightarrow \binom{2N}{k}p^kq^{2N-k}$$

where $\binom{2N}{k}$ is the binomial coefficient.

This formula gives the probability of obtaining $k$ copies of an allele at generation $t+1$ given that there is a frequency of $p$ of this allele in the population at generation $t$. $N$ is the population size and $2N$ is the number of copies of each gene (this model applies to [diploid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ploidy) population only).

My questions are:

- **1) From this formula, how can we calculate the probability of extinction of an allele in say 120 generations starting at a given frequency, let's say 0.2?**

and

- **2) How can we calculate the probability of extinction rather than fixation of an allele starting at frequency $p$ if we wait an infinite amount of time?**

**Question 2) has already been answered. Remain Question 1)**

---

[In 1969, Kimura and Ohta](http://www.genetics.org/content/61/3/763.full.pdf) showed that assuming an initial frequency of $p$, the mean time to fixation $\bar t_1(p)$ is:

$$\bar t_1(p)=-4N\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)\ln(1-p)$$

similarly they showed that the mean time to loss $\bar t_0(p)$ is

$$\bar t_0(p)=-4N\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)\ln(p)$$

Combining the two, they found that the **mean persistence time** of an allele $\bar t(p)$ is given by $\bar t(p) = (1-p)\bar t_0(p) + p\bar t_1(p)$ which equals

$$\bar t(p)=-4N\cdot \left((1-p)\cdot \ln(1-p)+p\cdot \ln(p)\right)$$

It does not answer my questions though!

---

I asked this same question on Biology.SE ([here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/11133/probability-of-extinction-under-genetic-drift)) a month ago but did not get an answer yet. I hope mathematician will be able to help me with that. On this biology.SE post, @GriffinEvo found via simulations that the probability of extinction of an allele starting at frequency $p$ if we wait an infinite amount of time is $1-p$ (which answer to question `2)`). How can we mathematically demonstrate that result? And don't forget question `1)` :D

Comment: here is the simulation script for use in R http://griffinevo.wordpress.com/2013/10/18/fisher-wright-genetic-drift-simulation-for-use-in-r/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Question 1) Let $X_n$ denote the population at time $n$, hence the step $n\to n+1$ uses the frequency $p_n=X_n/(2N)$. The transition probabilities yield, for every parameter $|s|\leqslant1$,
$$
E[s^{X_{n+1}}]=\sum_k{2N\choose k}p_n^kq_n^{2N-k}s^k=(p_ns+q_n)^{2N}=E\left[\left(1-(1-s)p_n\right)^{2N}\right],
$$
thus,
$$
P[X_{n}=0]=\lim_{s\to0}E[s^{X_n}]=E\left[\left(1-p_{n-1}\right)^{2N}\right].
$$
It is notoriously impossible to iterate exactly these recursions. However, $1-u\leqslant\mathrm e^{-u}$ for every $u$, hence 
$$\left(1-(1-s)p_{n-1}\right)^{2N}\leqslant\mathrm e^{-(1-s)X_{n-1}},
$$
which yields
$$
E[s^{X_n}]\leqslant E\left[\mathrm e^{-(1-s)X_{n-1}}\right].
$$
This can be rewritten as the fact that, for every $t\geqslant0$,
$$
E[\mathrm e^{-tX_n}]\leqslant E[\mathrm e^{-a(t)X_{n-1}}],\qquad a(t)=1-\mathrm e^{-t}.
$$
In particular,
$$
P[X_n=0]\leqslant E[\mathrm e^{-X_{n-1}}]\leqslant \mathrm e^{-a^{n-1}(1)X_0}.
$$
To iterate approximately $a$ near $0$, note that $\frac1{a(t)}=\frac1t+\frac12+o(1)$ when $t\to0$ hence $\frac1{a^n(1)}\sim\frac{n}2$ when $n\to\infty$. Finally, $X_0=2Np$ hence
$$
P[X_n=0]\leqslant\mathrm e^{-4Np/n+o(1/n)}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Question 2 is pretty straightforward. The Markov chain $X_n$ that tracks the frequency of the allele is a martingale, so that $\mathbb{E}(X_T)=\mathbb{E}(X_0)$ where $T$ is the fixation time. But $\mathbb{E}(X_T)=\mathbb{P}(X_T=1)$ which is the probability that this allele fixes. And $\mathbb{E}(X_0)$ is just the initial frequency $p$. Therefore, the chance of ultimate fixation is just the initial frequency.

This is Exercises 6.3.7 and 6.3.8 in *Probability: Theory and Examples (4th edition)* by Richard Durrett.